# Capturing Selenium Web-driver Json-wire HTTP interactions

Tags: http, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

Selenium Webdriver interacts with any browser through HTTP, as discussed - [here](https://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html).
I have some automated tests written using selenium through the Protractor framework in JavaScript.

My use case is I want a clean way to record all interactions originating from my JS-based test cases to the browser, including - user action emulations and any DOM interrogations originating from test-cases.

What would be the easiest way to record these interactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the interaction is over HTTP, I was able to capture the HTTP calls using - [httflow](https://github.com/six-ddc/httpflow) library.
Once I got the HTTP calls, I sanitized the HTTP dump to remove irrelevant calls and then mapped the Protractor code areas to the calls by defining a custom mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is a wrapper around [`Webdriverjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverjs/v/1.7.3) , so you should be able to use `addEventListener` command to add any browser supported [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) that will cover most user actions and DOM interrogations

Note, this is only supported in chrome currently

Also, this is an experimental feature in webdriver.js so have to add

```
var client = WebdriverJS.remote({
    logLevel: 'verbose',
    experimental: true, // <-- enables browser side eventhandling
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
});
```

And then register events like

```
client
    .url('http://google.com')
    .addEventListener('dblclick','#hplogo', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target); // -> 'id("hplogo")'
        console.log(e.type); // -> 'dblclick'
        console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY); // -> 239 524
    })
    .doubleClick('#hplogo') // triggers event
    .end();
```

You can use `removeEventListener` to unregister any registered listeners

Evenhandling in Node.js environment is also supported as implied by this

`WebdriverJS inherits several function from the NodeJS EventEmitter object`

If you want to also capture network  traffic , you can do that with [`browsermob-proxy`](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)

[Here](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/browsermob-proxy-selenium-example) is a tutorial on browsermob-proxy